# Webscraping Selenium but Website has multiple html and body tags

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

https://www.aektirol.at/arztsuche
I am looking at this website and want to scrape the doctors' information. Under each doctor's "card" is a detail button. When clicked, a new object tag is generated inside the html-code with new "body" and "html" tags.

With selenium I am not able to focus on this part of the code and can't retrieve the information I want. [Image of the generated object withhin the full html code. I want to scrape these data-parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpO7I.png)

Comment: Did you check with requests lib ?